# Saved files not showing immediately on Desktop

Tags: macos, finder, desktop

Often, I like to save files (screenshots, text files, etc) temporarily to the Desktop.

This was no problem with previous versions of OS X, but since updating to Yosemite, I have to relaunch the Finder to reveal the saved files.

My system is: Macbook Pro 13″ 3.1GHz 1TB 16GB RAM running Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: I didn't see this under Yosemite but I've been seeing it intermittently under Sierra. Annoying. :( So far I haven't found any fix but to kill/relaunch the Finder either.

Comment: Possibly related to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238629/21650)?

Comment: I have Mojave 10.14.3 and when I drag a picture, or take a screenshot to the desktop it take about 30 seconds to show up. It used to be immediate. Very frustrating!

Comment: Did you relaunch your computer for a try? Or do you upgrade to the Yosemite beta version?