# Files do not appear on Desktop nor does Drag & Drop work

Tags: macos, finder, desktop

I am using 10.11.4 OS X (El Capitan) . I don’t know when exactly these stopped working - files don't appear on the Desktop. Drag & Drop and popping up context menu with right click are not working on either.

I’ve Googled this problem and haven’t found a solution. Does anyone have any suggestions to fixing this?

Comment: I don't know now, sometimes it does work you say? You can try relaunching finder cmd-optn-esc and then choose finder), you can try checking the disk in Disk Utility, try resetting p-ram (reboot holding command-option-p-r till it reboots a second time). Also 10.11.5 is out, it might have a fix.

Comment: Other than that I would wonder do you have enough ram, do you have plenty of room on your hard drive, does activity monitor show that your CPU isn't too busy doing other things. Maybe there's a rogue process taking up all the ram or cpu so the computer can't deal with the desktop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just in case it's your preferences that have got corrupted somehow, you could try the following two commands in the Terminal:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true
$ killall Finder
```